# How to set draft option for Inkscape figures?

Tags: inkscape, draft

I read that it is possible to pass a draft option to the graphicx package in order to speed up typesetting. However, I am using Inkscape figures via

```
\begin{figure}
\input{myfigure.pdf_tex}
\end{figure}
```

(see http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/svg-inkscape/InkscapePDFLaTeX.pdf).

Is there a way to set a draft option, or so, for these kind of figures, so that LaTeX does not spend time on rendering them?

Comment: `\usepackage{ifdraft}` and say `\ifdraft{}{\input{...}}` within your figure, perhaps?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks. Good to know this option. Somehow I managed to put the draft option on a child document. The Inkscape figure is actually already handled by the draft option.

Comment: Ah, I see. Perhaps you should post a self-answer then. I never worked with Inkscape yet for production, only tests so far.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Done. Tried to make the best out of the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that the draft option also applies to Inkscape figures when set as a class option. For individual figures see [Christian Hupfer's comment above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467756/how-to-set-draft-option-for-inkscape-figures?noredirect=1#comment1176647_467756).